# Socket response header as hexadecimal format on two digits

Tags: swift, sockets, hex

I have a TCP socket connection where I am trying to respond to a request message. The specification I have states a response to a request should be in the format of:

[image: Header Data]

Where the header contains the data length in hexadecimal format on two digits. My response data is `"202000000000000TEST0_OK  "`.

As the response is 25 characters long, I assumed the header would be the hex representation of 25, so 0x19. However, when sending this, I'm getting an unknown error back from the device I'm replying to.

Using the `BlueSocket` library, I'm sending my response using:

```
if(message.contains("00000000000000001")) {
    reply = "202000000000000TEST0_OK  "
    var header: UInt8 = 0x19
    try socket.write(from: Data.init(bytes: &header, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size))
    try socket.write(from: reply)
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any further error information. I'm pretty confident my understanding of how to calculate and send the header is incorrect...

**Edit:** I've also tried the following responses which all failed:

- `"25XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` Started with the decimal length of the data string (25).
- `"27XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` Prepended with the entire length of the data and header string (27).
- `"19XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` Prepended with the hex representation of the length of the data string (25 characters so 0x19).
- `"1BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` Prepended with the hex representation of the entire length of the data and header string (27 characters so 0x1B).

Comment: Maybe it is expecting the string `"19"`.  So your reply would be `"reply = "19202000000000000TEST0_OK  "`.  Just a guess.

Comment: @vacawama - Sensible guess, but unfortunately that wasn't it. I've edited the question to show similar ones I have just tried. I keep asking myself why couldn't they have provided a simple example request/response in the documentation!!

Comment: 1. Are you sure you're reading the specification correctly? what exactly does it say? 2. Is your socket the one sending a response or the one sending a request? Maybe requests use a different format...?

Comment: After analysing the request in Wireshark, I noticed the request message started with the null character 0x00. Adding this to my response did the trick, so 0x00 0x19... I've triple checked the docs and there is no reference to this. A simple issue, which an example in the docs would have taken 2 minutes to spot, instead of 2 days.